# Vagrant: произвольные команды

Tags: vagrant

Я продолжаю пилить идеальный бутстрап репозитория с использованием vagrant, хочется функционала маппинга команд vagrant, которые позволили бы исполнять произвольные команды внутри машины (простейший пример: `vagrant test → /var/www/project/bin/codecept run Unit --env=vagrant`). Пока что натолкнулся только на плагин exec, который позволит пробрасывать команды, но не подменять их короткими алиасами, и вот на [эту штуку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037083), которая превратит vagrantfile в бардак. Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение, которое позволит мне осуществить задуманное без излишней костыльности? vagrant-exec был бы идеальным решением, если бы позволял маппить команды.

upd прочитал про binstubs в том же vagrant-exec, уже куда ближе к цели, но не хотелось бы мусорить в проекте файлами.

upd 2 пока что решил через

```
config.exec.commands 'test', directory: synced_folder,
    prepend: 'bin/codecept run --env=vagrant #'
```

но это дьявольский костыль

Answer (score 1):

Внедрение произвольных команд для vagrant я сделал следующим образом.

Создал скрипт, в котором будут храниться команды для provision. Например проброс своих ключей.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat /vagrant/ssh_keys/id_rsa > /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
 cat /vagrant/ssh_keys/id_rsa.pub > /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
 echo "test" >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

В Vagranfile добавить следующую строку:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "scripts/setup.sh", run: "always", privileged: true
```

Опцию `privileged` нужно указывать, если необходимо запустить скрипт в привилигерованном режиме, т.е sudo.
Опция `always` указывает на то, как часто нужно выполнять скрипт. В моем случае всегда. Если нужно один раз, укажите `once`.